# Jquery - Setting value of <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a table and in 1 column a Delete link, if the user clicks this link it fires an onClick which basically flags that item to be deleted and hide the TR.
It works fine, but I am just wondering if there is a better way .....

```
$(document).on('click', '.deleteCell', function (e) {
    //Belt and braces - only do this for <td> elements
    var target = $(e.target);
    if (!target.is('td')) {return;}

    var h = this.innerHTML;
    var newH = h.replace("CsUpdated", "CsDeleted");
    newH = newH.replace("CsAdded", "CsDeleted");
    this.innerHTML = newH;

    //We clicked on a TD so get the row TR.       
    var theRow = $(this).closest('tr');
    theRow.hide();
});
```

I just think there must be a better way than the string manipulation I am doing with the replace?  Is there?
I've tried these but with no luck...

```
$(this).attr('value', 'CsDeleted');
$(target).attr('value', 'CsDeleted');
$(this).val('CsDeleted');
$(target).val('CsDeleted');
```

Thanks

Comment: use .text() or .html()

Comment: Table data cells don't have values. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Hete is the TD


        <td value="CsDeleted" class="deleteCell">
            <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The ModelStatus field is required." id="Costs_0__ModelStatus" name="Costs[0].ModelStatus" value="CsDeleted" type="hidden">
            Delete
        </td>

I want to modify the value of ModelStatus.
I see now it is in the input...excude me.
I just need to be able to get the Input element now.

Answer (score 3):

td has no value use `.text()` or `.html()`

Comment: That amounts to string manipulation which the op wants to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

`td` doesnt have a `value` attribute.

Use

```
$("td").html() // to fetch html
$("td").html("<span> Hello World </span>") // to set html

$("td").text() // to fetch plain text
$("td").text("Hello World") // to set plain text
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use custom `data-`- attributes on any html element ( see [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) and [the reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) ). These are accessible through  jquery's `attr` method and have no influence on rendering.

Code PoC:

```
$(document).on('click', 'td.deleteCell', function (e) {
    //Belt and braces - only do this for <td> elements

    $(this)
        .removeAttr('data-CsUpdated')
        .removeAttr('data-CsAdded')
        .attr('CsDeleted', '1')
    ;

    //We clicked on a TD so get the row TR.       
    $(this).closest('tr').hide();
});
```

In case the values given in your code are mutually exclusive, this simplifies to

```
$(document).on('click', 'td.deleteCell', function (e) {
    //Belt and braces - only do this for <td> elements

    $(this).attr('Cs', 'Deleted');
       // attr 'Cs' contained 'Added' or 'Updated'
       // This scheme requires modifications at other places in your original code !
    ;

    //We clicked on a TD so get the row TR.       
    $(this).closest('tr').hide();
});
```

**Update**

As the OP actually wants to modify the value of a child `input` element, the handler reduces to:

```
$(document).on('click', 'td.deleteCell', function (e) {
    $('input', $(this)).val('CsDeleted');
        // more specific selector may be needed depending on possible cell contents

    $(this).closest('tr').hide();
});
```

Comment: This does just the job - Thanks.
So I'm reading it as....for the 'inpu' inside 'this' set the value to be 'csDeleted'..Correct?

Just to assist my understanding of this, if I wanted to get the Input into a var and then set the Vars value......
Would it be.....?

        var myInput = $('input', $(this));
        myInput.val('CsDeleted');

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use any of the following to set the cell contents

`.html()` or `.text()` or `.prepend`or `.append` and more

However `.val()` only works on inputs that have the `value="...."` attribute. If you want to prop the Cell with some data use `.data("key","value")` which can be accessed at any point by calling `.data("key");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
$(function(){
$('.delete').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  });
```

});